# Launch FreeBSD 8.4 (and newer) under qemu/kvm

Tags: freebsd, qemu, kvm

I'm trying to launch FreeBSD releases since 6.0 and never in virtual machines, using `qemu-2.0.0+dfsg-2ubuntu1.10` (qemu-kvm) and `virt-manager-1:1.1.0-1~getdeb3`.

All releases under 8.4 (and also 9.0) runs fine with the same settings of vm, but I can't launch 8.4+ (9.1+): they go into loop just after some seconds after boot starts. The error message during boot loop is:

```
Fatal trap 12: page fault while in kernel mode
...
fault code   = supervisor read data, page not present
```

[image: error during booting FreeBSD 8.4 into qemu-kvm]

I know, that 8.4 brings a lot of virtio stuff in the FreeBSD kernel. Theoretically it should make working into VM easier, but I just can't figure out what is the problem with my environment.

How make my FreeBSD 8.4 working into qemu-kvm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is in model of virtualized CPU. Changing processor model from "Hypervisor Default" to "KVM64" in `virt-manager` GUI solves this problem.